# document.getElementById(id).focus() is not working for firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript

When ever I do onchange event, its going inside that function its validating, But focus is not comming I am using `document.getElementById('controlid').focus();`

I am using Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome, in both its not working. I don't want any IE. Can any one tell me what could me the reason.

Here's the code:

```
var mnumber = document.getElementById('mobileno').value; 
if(mnumber.length >=10) {
    alert("Mobile Number Should be in 10 digits only"); 
    document.getElementById('mobileno').value = ""; 
    document.getElementById('mobileno').focus(); 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can see what's going on.  Also, try and clean up your question a little.

Comment: Are you doing this in the onload handler?

Comment: Ok.. I am doing mobile no. validation, in that onchange  event I written like this 
var mnumber= document.getElementById('mobileno').value;

if(mnumber.length >=10){
    alert("Mobile Number Should be in 10 digits only");
    
   document.getElementById('mobileno').value="";
   document.getElementById('mobileno').focus();
       return false;
}

here if any one enters digits less than 10 it will show alert and clear the text field after that the focus is going next field, I am trying to give in same field its not comming for Mozilla and crome.

Comment: did u add 'index' attribute to ur html?

Answer (score 147):

Try using a timer:

```
const id = "mobileno";
const element = document.getElementById(id);
if (element.value.length >= 10) {
    alert("Mobile Number Should be in 10 digits only");
    element.value = "";
    window.setTimeout(() => element.focus(), 0);
    return false;
}
```

A timer with a count of 0 will run when the thread becomes idle.  If that doesn't help, try the code (with the timer) in the `onblur` event instead.

Comment: I don't like not to understand because I forget everything but when I understand something I JUST UNDERSTAND IT and I don't need to remember it. So I have a question for @AndyE, where did you learn that? I would loooove to read about javascript specifications I know that implementations will not necessarily follow but when you say "_will run when the thread becomes idle_" I immediately understood why it wasn't working. So I would like to learn about internals.

Comment: Wanting to dig this up but yeah as some concerns above, why does this work?

Comment: An explanation can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955650/what-is-settimeout-doing-when-set-to-0-milliseconds/33955673 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: This is also a really good visual representation of the JS event loop https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5

Comment: @AndyE  Soooper curious to know exactly how it works any refer please???

Comment: +1. For me, using AngularJS, my problem seemed to be that an `md-tab` transition was preventing `focus()` from working unless I used `window.setTimeout` with 200 ms.

Answer (score 77):

2 things to mention if `focus()` not working:

- use this function after appending to parent
- if console is selected, after refreshing page, element will not gain focus, so select (click on) the webpage while testing

This way works in both Firefox and Chrome without any `setTimeOut()`.

Comment: Closing the console in Chrome indeed solved this weird issue.

Comment: dammit! you saved me hours of debugging, indeed when the console is selected the focus method does not work. If I knew you I'd buy you a beer!

Comment: I always forgot about the console -.- thanks for remembering me =)

Comment: I also had the Firefox Development Tools (i.e. `console`) opened, and closing it fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thanks for clarification about console. Cause I was wondering why my simple a[0].focus() doesn't work

Comment: kisses for @Boaz

Comment: still not working for me. It is even working in IE11

Comment: Thanks @user669677 with my console open it was not working. Adding a timeout function allowed me to focus on my window and the onfocus worked.

Answer (score 43):

My case was a bit different. I was trying to `focus()` an input from within a browser developer console. Turns out it was interfering with the input somehow, and once I minimized the console everything worked **as expected**. I understand this isn't a programmatical solution, but in case someone found this on a search engine jist like I did, there's a chance this information might help.

Comment: This is actually the answer ! Chrome Dev Tools are preventing the focus action.

Comment: And I was mad for 2 hours, tried everything, but with open chrome dev tools

Comment: Correct in my case! I used Chrome Web Tools and could not figure out why it did not work. Once I closed Chrome Web Tools, it focused on the element I wanted.

Answer (score 38):

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById('mobileno').focus(); 
}, 0);
```

This worked for me also. Firefox would set the value of my element, but not give focus to it.

Comment: The easy solution for me was this, though with a 500ms delay. I guess something tries to steal the focus and its probably possible to dig further and determine who/what it is.

Answer (score 28):

Not all elements are focusable but default, there is a tabindex attribute to fix that.

When you assign tabindex= to an element:

It becomes focusable. A user can use the tab key to move from the element with lesser positive tabindex to the next one. The exception is a special value tabindex="0" means that the element will always be last. The tabindex=-1 means that an element becomes focusable, but the tab key will always skip it. Only the focus() method will work

Comment: Great explanation.fixed all my tabIndex issues

Comment: This fixed it. Using window.setTimeout or closing the console might fix the issue temporarily, but should still use tabindex for safety.

Comment: 'tabindex="0" means that the element should be focusable in sequential keyboard navigation, after any positive tabindex values and its order is defined by the document's source order.' https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 12):

One more thing to add to this list to check:

Make sure the element you are trying to focus is not itself nor is contained in an element with "display: none" at the time you are trying to focus it.

Answer (score 4):

For getting back focus to retype password text box in javascript:

```
window.setTimeout(function() { document.forms["reg"]["retypepwd"].focus(); },0);
```

Here, `reg` is the registration form name.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the reason this works is the browser rendering runs on the same thread as javascript, and setTimeout(function(){},0); queues the javascript function inside setTimeout to execute when the browser becomes idle. If anyone has a more in-depth explanation please share it.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
 if(document.getElementById('mobileno')){
  document.getElementById('mobileno').focus();
 } 
},0);
```

Answer (score 3):

The timeout suggested above worked around the issue on Chrome. No issue exists on IE8 or FF3.

My code that to set focus that worked is:

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
  document.form1.password.focus();
}, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for keeping me from banging my head against anything solid and big. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be an esoteric use-case but I struggled with getting an input to take focus when using Angular 2 framework. Calling focus() simply did not work not matter what I did.

Ultimately I realized angular was suppressing it because I had not set an [(ngModel)] on the input. Setting one solved it. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this type of problem in `vue js`.

I fixed this problem using vue `$nextTick` method
`Vue 2`

```
this.$nextTick(() => {                      
    this.$refs['ref-name'].focus(); 
});
```

you can use it inside of `vue js` mounted lifecycle hooks.

Comment: The question is not tagged with vue js. as such it's unlikely that people will find this answer (useful)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: well, I did find it useful. Most frameworks have a `tick` situation and due to that element not focusing.

Comment: This topic was the first thing i found when looking for a solution, i also use Vue (3) so this answered my question. +1

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to reference the element before the DOM has finished loading?

Your code should go in body load (or another function that should execute when the DOM has loaded, such as `$(document).ready()` in jQuery)

```
body.onload = function() { 
    // your onchange event handler should be in here too   
    var mnumber = document.getElementById('mobileno').value; 
    if(mnumber.length >=10) {
        alert("Mobile Number Should be in 10 digits only"); 
        document.getElementById('mobileno').value = ""; 
        document.getElementById('mobileno').focus(); 
        return false; 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use "id" and "getElementById" as shown here:

```
<FORM id="my_form" name="my_form" action="">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="somefield" ID="somefield" onChange="document.getElementById('my_form').submit();">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a control, where you want to set focus then change its property like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDummy" runat="server" Text="" Width="2" ReadOnly="true" BorderStyle="None" BackColor="Transparent"></asp:TextBox>
```

In the codebehind, just call like below
`txtDummy.Focus()`

this method is working in all browser.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check  that I just found is that it won't work if there are multiple elements with the same ID. It doesn't error if you try to do this, it just fails silently

Answer (score 0):

Your focus is working before return false;  ,After that is not working.  You try this solution. Control after return false;

Put code in function:

```
function  validateNumber(){
    var mnumber = document.getElementById('mobileno').value; 
    if(mnumber.length >=10) {
        alert("Mobile Number Should be in 10 digits only"); 
        document.getElementById('mobileno').value = ""; 
        return false; 
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Caller function:

```
function submitButton(){
        if(!validateNumber()){
            document.getElementById('mobileno').focus();
            return false;
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
Input:<input type="text" id="mobileno">
<button onclick="submitButton();" >Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this source above your modal :

```
<script>
$('body').on('shown.bs.modal', '#IdYourModal', function () {
    document.getElementById('mobileno').focus();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use `.focus()` to move my scroll position so the target element was visible.

Turns out that `.focus()` isn't designed to do this - it's for "focusing" on a form element, or at least something that's focusable (such as an `<a>`).

The correct function to call was `.scrollIntoView()`.

```
document.getElementById('mobileno').scrollIntoView();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the tabIndex of your element is -1. In my case it helped to set it to a positive number.

`element.tabIndex = 1`

Answer (score -1):

Try `location.href='#yourId'`

Like this:

```
<button onclick="javascript:location.href='#yourId'">Show</button>
```