# Why doesn't focus() select my container div?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an index.html which has JavaScript:

```
byId("p").value = page;
byId("nav_container").focus();
document.forms["nav_form_main"].submit();
```

The focus part doesn't work here.

I want the browser to focus on a specific part of the page (almost at top).

I have tried putting the focus after the submit(), same issue there.

Comment: I presume `byId()` is a shortcut function for `document.getElementById()`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

make sure the element you want to focus has an attribute  `tabindex="-1"`, otherwise that element is not focusable.

For example

```
<div id="myfocusablediv" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

When you set the tabindex=-1 for an element it allows it to get focus() through javascript. If instead you want it to get focus through tabbing through elements, then you would set the tabindex attribute to 0.

Comment: The tabindex part is good, but it doen't have to be -1, it could be any value that makes sense for that specific page.

Comment: For my case nothing change. I was also not able to get the focus also from console command, and din't know why(tried both pure javascript and jquery).

Comment: On chrome try focus() by closing dev-tool https://stackoverflow.com/a/41474220/7026966

Comment: if the element is dynamically added, wait for a bit
```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('.my input').focus();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Here's what I do when I want to force a certain form element to have focus:

```js
function setFocusFixed( elm ){
    if( !input ) return;

    var savedTabIndex = elm.getAttribute('tabindex')
    elm.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')
    elm.focus()
    elm.setAttribute('tabindex', savedTabIndex)
}

// DEMO: 

var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button'),
    input   = document.querySelector('input');

buttons[0].addEventListener('click', ()=>input.focus())
buttons[1].addEventListener('click', ()=>setFocusFixed(input))
```

```html
<input placeholder='some input' tabindex='2' />
<button>Set focus on input</button>
<button>Set focus on input - fixed</button>
```

This little function simply sets the form field `tabindex` to `-1` so the DOM `focus()` method could take affect, and immediately sets it back to its original value.

### Update Aug 2019:

Seems that on *Chrome 76* giving focus works as it should, without the `-1` `tabindex` trick.

Answer (score 6):

You need an attribute `tabindex="0"` to be able to focus (works for me) : `tabindex="-1"` remove the element from the page tab sequence (it is no longer focusable with keyboard for instance).

- -1 is still focusable in some cases but not by keyboard (tab key),
- 0 is focusable in an automatic order
- Any other positive number defines the order to focus elements

https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/tabs/tabs-1/tabs.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have devtools open. I just came across this and when I closed devtools everything worked fine.

Comment: yes I agree, I came up with the same issue. If deveoper tools is open your DOMelement.focu() may not work

Comment: It happened to me too in Firefox. Very strange. Does anyone know why or how to avoid it while keeping devtools open?

Answer (score 3):

Once you submit the form, any focus becomes irrelevant. The document changes location to the form's action and the focus is lost anyway.

Looks like you want to set focus **after** the submit, in this case do it in the onload event:

```
window.onload = function WindowLoad(evt) {
   byId("nav_container").focus();
}
```

As mentioned by others, if "nav_container" is not input box it won't work either and to scroll to that position use named anchor instead.. add such anchor before the element:

```
<a name="nav_container_anchor" />
```

Then have such JS code to scroll to that location:

```
document.location = "#nav_container_anchor";
```