# $.focus() not working

Tags: jquery

The [last example of jQuery's `focus()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) states

```
$('#id').focus()
```

should make the input focused (active). I can't seem to get this working.

Even in the console on this site, I'm trying it for the search box

```
$('input[name="q"]').focus()
```

and I'm getting nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: We'll have to know more, because it works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/G7hwR/1/ just click anywhere in the right panel and it focuses...

Comment: Shouldn't the focus on this page work, though? The snippet I provided?

Comment: It depends on what it's contained in; if it's not inside anything, it's likely being run before the page even renders...

Comment: For those coming here from search: the browser's built in developer tools might interfere with the `focus()` funcionality. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41474220/722036)

Comment: May try at first `$('#id').blur();` then `$('#id').focus()` For me this worked in one situation. In other words remove focus, then set focus. Instead of remove focus, may set focus to another input, then set back to necessary input. Crazy solution, but... This problem noticed in Chrome, Edge. In FF all ok.

Answer (score 489, accepted):

Actually the example you gave for focusing on this site works just fine, as long as you're not focused in the console. The reason that's not working is simply because it's not stealing focus from the dev console. If you run the following code in your console and then quickly click in your browser window after, you will see it focus the search box:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="q"]').focus() }, 3000);
```

As for your other one, the one thing that has given me trouble in the past is order of events. You cannot call focus() on an element that hasn't been attached to the DOM. Has the element you are trying to focus already been attached to the DOM?

Comment: That was it. I swore it wasn't a timing issue (it was), but I was going crazy because it wasn't working from the console. I swear I've done it from the console before. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Did that help with both of your problems? If so, could you mark it as the correct answer? I would much appreciate it :D

Comment: don't use developer tools when only use $('input[name="q"]').focus();or not work

Comment: Wow, I'd been struggling on and off with this for months, I only just saw that this is caused by the developer console being open. Mine always is. Thank you!

Comment: +1 for "You cannot call focus() on an element that hasn't been attached to the DOM." Also, it seems you can't call it on hidden elements.

Comment: Can someone explain why you have to use setTimeout for this to work? It is working for me, but I would like more info into the "why".

Comment: Simply because you need time to click on the page to move your browser's focus back to the page. Remember, the problem is that the page cannot steal focus from the developer console. That would be extremely annoying as a developer if the page could steal your focus.

Comment: Using `setTimeout` to solve order of operations problems makes it a huge pain in the patooty to maintain. If a bug shows up it's really hard to debug. Wherever you are inserting the element into the DOM, it should call `.focus()` there.

Comment: @KevinBeal If you read the text above the example you will see that it is not instructing to use `setTimeout` as a solution. It is simply being used as a demonstration on this site of the dev console focus prevent jQuery `focus()` calls from working. It should never be used as a solution where it creates race conditions.

Comment: I was having the same issue. My issue was happening because I was calling .focus() on an element that had its CSS 'display' property set to 'none'. I moved the call to .focus() to after a call to .show() and this solved it.

Comment: The length of timeout does not seem to matter.  In a similar situation, I was able to get away with a 1 millisecond timeout.

Comment: @JasonL. Your problem sounds like a simple timing issue. You most likely created an element and then tried to focus before attaching it to the DOM. In any case, if 1 ms timeout is working for you then 0 will probably work just as well. All that does immediately add the work to the event queue to run as soon as the current execution context completes.

Comment: @JustinWarkentin, based on your solution, i should put first `$(window).focus();`, right?

Comment: @ebramtharwat No, that will not work. The page cannot steal focus from the dev console. If you have the dev console focused you will not see `focus()` calls work on the page. That is why I did a `setTimeout()` in the answer here (don't do that in your code). It gives you time to click back on the page and see the `focus()` call work.

Comment: I was trying to focus onto a field that was appearing in a Bootstrap modal. Adding a timeout with 500 ms fixed this for me. Without the timeout, the field wasn't getting put in focus.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst Bootstrap provides an event so you can focus when it's ready. They give an example for focusing at the bottom of the modal section [here](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: Should probably be mentioned that 3000 ms is way too much in probably all cases, used 200 ms for an input in a popup window.

Comment: @David The point of 3000 ms was to give time to click out of the dev console to demonstrate that the reason focus() wasn't working on this site was just that you can't steal focus from the dev console. In an app using a timeout is always a hack and a bad idea. Code should be refactored to be properly event driven so focus() is always called after the element is attached to the DOM and there is no possibility of a race condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JustinWarkentin. I wanted to upvote 10 times but can't. You saved me.

Comment: "as long as you're not focused in the console" I really feel like an idiot for not realizing that sooner, I just thought .focus() was broken and moved on

Comment: Had the same problem while trying to set focus to an input field from a select2-enhanced select. A timeout of 1 sec was enough. Thanks

Comment: This ultimately helped me solve a similar problem while trying to set focus inside an angular event handler: the element which I was trying to focus was still invisible (`display: none`) until the end of "current job".... turns out I needed a `async` or `animationFrame` scheduler, so angular could have enough time to display said element.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried to focus from the code (not the console) - and it works!

Answer (score 88):

Found a solution elsewhere on the net...

```
$('#id').focus();
```

did not work.

```
$('#id').get(0).focus();
```

did work.

Comment: I upvoted this solution merely because it worked for me when the more popular solution on this page did not. ;-)

Comment: The second option just seems to be grabbing the dom element and using the regular javascript version instead of the jquery version.

Comment: Could it be that you have multiple elements with id "id" on your page? The DOM will not break in this case but you can't assign focus to multiple elements either

Comment: I found I had to do this with a window.setTimeout with a delay of 0, and then all is well. Thanks. Everything else I tried failed in a bootstrap modal.

Comment: If there is a label with for="same_as_input_id", then you have to use .get(0).

Comment: Or even shorter: `$('#id')[0].focus();`.

Comment: This is still the only thing that works in 2021. I added first() to my selector but focus() would not work without explicitly adding [0]. ???!!!!

Comment: How would you get this working with plain javascript?

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I was working on a custom modal and getting that thing to be accessible was such a pain. ```$('#id').get(0).focus();``` helped me set the focus. For whatever reason, ```$('#id').focus();``` did not.

Comment: This did not work for me

Answer (score 26):

Some of the answers here suggest using `setTimeout` to delay the process of focusing on the target element.  One of them mentions that the target is inside a modal dialog.  I cannot comment further on the correctness of the `setTimeout`solution without knowing the specific details of where it was used.

The simple fact of the matter is that *you cannot focus on an element which is not yet visible*.  If you run into this problem **ensure that the target is actually visible** when the attempt to focus it is made.  In my own case I was doing something along these lines:

```
$('#elementid').animate({left:0,duration:'slow'});
$('#elementid').focus();
```

This did not work.  I only realized what was going on when I executed $('#elementid').focus()` from the console which **did** work.  The difference - in my code above the target there is no certainty that the target will infact be visible since the animation may not be *complete*.  And there lies the clue:

```
$('#elementid').animate({left:0,duration:'slow',complete:focusFunction});

function focusFunction(){$('#elementid').focus();}
```

works just as expected.  I too had initially put in a `setTimeout` solution and it worked too.  However, an arbitrarily chosen timeout is bound to break the solution sooner or later depending on how slowly the host device goes about the process of ensuring that the target element is visible.

Comment: The relevant hint for me was "ensure that the target is actually visible". this becomes relevant when trying to focus on conditionally rendered elements.

Comment: Or when element to focus has `visibility:hidden` - it won't get focused.

Comment: ` you cannot focus on an element which is not yet visible` - I love you. By simply adding a 100ms timeout I could trigger the focus on my hidden search box. Thanks!

Comment: Beware of timeouts.  What  works on your development machine may well not work on another one.

Comment: I note that this answer is still getting upvotes seven years after I posted it. As a more general comment for anyone still finding it useful **timeouts are evil**. Whenever you feel tempted to use a timeout pause for a minute and find a relevant event to use instead. _cherchez l'évènement_ to steal a French expression.

Answer (score 26):

if you use bootstrap + modal, this worked for me :

```
  $(myModal).modal('toggle');
  $(myModal).on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#modalSearchBox').focus()
  });
```

Comment: This worked when we use the bootstrap modal, thanks

Answer (score 13):

Just in case anybody else stumbles across this question and had the same situation I had - I was trying to set the focus after clicking on another element, yet the focus didn't appear to work. It turns out I just needed an `e.preventDefault();` - here's an example:

```
$('#recipients ul li').mousedown(function(e) {
    // add recipient to list
    ...
    // focus back onto the input
    $('#message_recipient_input').focus();
    // prevent the focus from leaving
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This helped:

> If you call HTMLElement.focus() from a mousedown event handler, you must call event.preventDefault() to keep the focus from leaving the HTMLElement. 
>   Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

Comment: The only one works! Trigger is a popup div, click hides the div and put some value in a text box (not the one need to be focused). Without preventDefault, that text box is always focused no matter what -__-

Answer (score 5):

I also had this problem. The solution that worked in my case was using the tabindex property on the HTML element.

I was using `ng-repeat` for some li elements inside a list and I was not able to bring focus to the first li using .focus(), so I simply added the tabindex attribute to each li during the loop.

so now `<li ng-repeat="user in users track by $index" tabindex="{{$index+1}}"></li>`

That +1 was index starts from 0.
Also make sure that the element is present in DOM before calling the .focus() function

I hope this helps.

Comment: [nice explanation on javascript.info](https://javascript.info/focus-blur#allow-focusing-on-any-element-tabindex)

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is old, but came across it today.  None of the answers worked for me, what I did find that worked was setTimeout.  I wanted my focus to be placed on the input filed of a modal, using the setTimeout worked.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Me too! AND the length of the timeout really made a difference. Stupid IE.

Comment: But it's not working on mobile devices. Mobile browsers are ignoring in most of the cases everything what is inside setTimeout

Comment: As a rule of thumb, using `setTimeout` is a _bad_ solution. You can't guarantee execution time on the user's machine, so time-dependent stuff is extremely fragile.

Answer (score 4):

Add a delay before focus(). 200 ms is enough

```
function focusAndCursor(selector){
  var input = $(selector);
  setTimeout(function() {
    // this focus on last character if input isn't empty
    tmp = input.val(); input.focus().val("").blur().focus().val(tmp);
  }, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Had this issue again just now, and believe it or not, all I had to do was close the developer tools. Apparently the Console tab has the focus priority over the page content.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, and in case someone else runs into this, I load a form for view, user clicks "Edit" and ajax gets & returns values and updates the form.

Just after this, I tried all of these and none worked except:

```
setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="q"]').focus() }, 3000);
```

which I had to change to (due to ajax):

```
setTimeout(function() { $('input[name="q"]').focus() }, **500**);
```

and I finally just used $("#q") even though it was an input:

```
setTimeout(function () { $("#q").focus() }, 500);
```

Answer (score 2):

For those with the problem of not working because you used "$(element).show()". I solved it the next way:

```
 var textbox = $("#otherOption");
 textbox.show("fast", function () {
    textbox[0].focus();
  });
```

So you dont need a timer, it will execute after the show method is completed.

Comment: This applies to any other transition: `slideDown()`, `fadeIn()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the element and its parents are visible.
You cannot use focus on hidden elements

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `id` is `tries`

```
window.location.hash = '#tries';
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue and wrapping the event within `setTimout` function worked perfectly for me.
But somehow it felt like this wasn't the best approach to resolve it (manually delaying the event).

However, In my case the focus event wasn't triggering as the element was invisible/hidden and it turns out that the element was visible after a few milliseconds as I was triggering the focus event within `element.on("focus")` function (which is a triggered when the element is clicked and the element is focused in).

This worked for me:

```js
element.on("focus", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (element.is(":visible")) {
    search_input.trigger("focus");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In case jquery wont work, you can easily make it work with **vanilla js**:

```
setTimeout(function() { document.querySelector("#id").focus() }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pro tip. If you want to turn on focus from the dev console then just open the console as a separate window from the options tab. The latest Firefox and Chrome supports this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I tested code from Chrome's DevTool Console and the focus part not worked. I found out later the issue is only present if i run it from DevTool and if i implement the code to the website it works fine.
Actually, the element got focused but the DevTool removed it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Setting tabindex=0 before focus() helped me

```
const $elOk = $modal.querySelector('.modal__button-ok');
$elOk.setAttribute('tabindex', '0');
$elOk.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.keypress()` was the issue for me.

Try using `.keyup()` or `.input()` if you are too.

`.keydown()` has odd behaviour. It moves the input to the new focus field.

Answer (score 0):

### 1 of 2 - Famous scenario (Try to set `focus` for unfocused element)

Same for `jquery` -or- `vanilla js`.

`focus()` work only if the `element` can be focused.

- `focusable` (By default) - for example: `a, button, input`
- `not focusable` (By default) - for example: `div, li, section, h1`

So if you try to set `focus` for `h1` you need to set [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

```js
$("h1").focus();
```

```html
<h1 tabindex="0">Focus</h1>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### 2 of 2 - Famous scenario (Try to set `focus` after click on `button` or `a`)

Same for `jquery` -or- `vanilla js`.

"The Problem" - `button` -or- `a` focus after click. So you need to `blur()` the button and only than change focus.

```js
$( "[open_modal]" ).on( "click", function(event) {
  this.blur();
  $("[modal]").attr('tabindex', '-1');
  $("[modal]").focus();
} );
```

```css
*:focus{
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" open_modal>focus modal</a>

<div modal>hello modal</div>
```

#### focus only by code

`tabindex="-1"` - means that the element is not reachable via sequential keyboard navigation. But still can be focus by `javascript` (For example `off-screen modal`).

```js
$( "[open_modal]" ).on( "click", function() {

  $("[modal]").attr('tabindex', '-1');
  document.querySelector('[modal]').focus();
  
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li href="#" open_modal>focus modal</li>

<div modal>hello modal</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For my case I had to specify a tab index (`-1` if only focusable via script)

```html
<div tabindex='-1'>
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

As this is a little old, ive added a current solution.
if you need to tab focus to the next input use
$("#elid").nextAll("input")[0].focus().
Occassionally you'll need to use a timout function to delay but 200ms should suffice
full example:

$(document).on("keyup", "#Advert input", function (e) {

```
       let el = $(e.target).closest("input")
       if (e.which == 13) {
      $(el).nextAll("input")[0].focus()
          
       }
   })
```

Comment: Adding more information and structure to your answer would likely make it more useful and informative. @Andyroo.

Answer (score -2):

ADDITIONAL SOLUTION Had same issue where focus() didn't seem to work but eventually it turned out that what was needed was scrolling to the correct position:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43342974/1335717