# How to move the cursor into a input text box by clicking on html button?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi Can anybody tell me How to move the cursor into a input text box by clicking on html button ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859113/focus-not-working by @justin-warkentin

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("textbox").focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my_textbox" value="My Text" />
<button id="my_button">Focus</button>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('my_button').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('my_textbox').focus();
};
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/GeoForce/ZnVH7/

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it by using `jQuery` as follows:

Include `jquery` in `HTML HEAD` section then

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
$( "#targetinput" ).focus();
});
```

Or without jquery you can do it using

```
getElementByID("targetinput").focus();
```