# Programatically put input in editing state (just like clicked on it with mouse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Assume there is a regular html input field

```
<input id="inputEl" type="text">
```

When I click on it with my mouse, it starts being 'editable' (an editing line at the beginning starts blinking) - just like every input field.

Using jQuery, I am trying to simulate that so without me clicking on it with mouse, it gets on that editing state.

I have tried:

- `$('#inputEl').click()`
- `$('#inputEl').keydown()`
- `$('#inputEl').focus()`
- `$('#inputEl').focusin()`
- `$('#inputEl').blur()`
- `$('#inputEl').select()`
- `$('#inputEl').trigger('input')`

But none seems to do the trick.

What is the proper way of achieving this?

Comment: "Focus" is the term you're looking for, FYI.

Comment: I think `.focus()` is the correct method

Comment: jQuery is definitely loaded, otherwise I'd get `$()` error. I just tried StackOverflow's search input at the top. `$('.js-search-field').focus()`. It doesn't do the trick either. Open up your console and try it. jQuery exists in SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.focus()` would be the correct method here, the problem you are facing could be related to other issues.

At least it is working here
http://jsfiddle.net/KN6rs/

The `focus()` function doesn't work on console because:
[$.focus() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859113/focus-not-working)

I tried
`setTimeout(function() { $('.js-search-field').focus() }, 3000);` works on SO

Comment: Yes, I think it is related to other issues. It works in your example; I also played with it and it works in there indeed. However, can you try putting StackOverflow's search input at the top in editing state? `$('.js-search-field').focus()` won't do the trick. You can try it by opening your console; jQuery is injected in SO.

Comment: @senty focus doesn't work on console because https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859113/focus-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to simulate `click` event. You can do it via jQuery using `trigger()`, like this:

```
$("#inputEl").trigger("click");
```

Here is an example:

```js
$("#inputEl").trigger("click");
function wasClicked() {
  console.log('Click event was successfully simulated')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputEl" type="text" onclick="wasClicked()">
```

Or if you want just to `focus` on this input, here it is:

```js
$("#inputEl").focus()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputEl" type="text">
```

Comment: Open up your console, and try putting the StackOverflow's search box at the top in that editing state, just like it is clicked with mouse. `$('.js-search-field').trigger("click");` won't put it on that mode.

Comment: Yes, this is the behaviour, but it is not working on SO's input for example. `$('.js-search-field').focus()` won't do the trick in that case

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#inputEl').focus();
});
```

This is your solution. You just need to do it when the DOM is loaded. $(document).ready takes care of that.