# Jquery focus method does not work for a textarea

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to focus on a textarea in my HTML. The textarea has a function to submit on enter.

```
<form id = "msgform"  method="POST" >
    {% csrf_token %}
        <textarea  id = "msg" name = "msg" > </textarea>
           
</form>
```

I have a function that focuses on the textarea on page load, and I want to do the same when my ajax call returns success

```
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'{{request.path}}',
  data:{
    value:$('#msg').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
  },
  
  success:function(data){  
   
    $( "#Wrap" ).load(window.location.href + " #M" );

    ('#msg').focus()
    
  }

})
```

The rest of the Ajax call works fine, but the **('#msg').focus()** does not work. What could be causing this?

Comment: I fixed it by using a setTimeout as shown by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859113/focus-not-working

Answer (score 0):

`('#msg').focus()` should be **`$('#msg').focus()`**

PS: besides the above, the problem might also to lie in the part of the code you did not provided, and that's the **Submit function**

Use: [**Event.preventDefault()** - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

A button inside a `form` that is not of `type="button"` by default triggers a form Submit Event and the browser usually follows the form's `action` URI and/or  does a page refresh (visible usually with the tab spinner, or i.e: inside Dev Tools *Network*)

To prevent that behavior use

```
$("#msgform").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // AJAX HERE
});
```

Comment: This is not the problem because the textarea actually uses a different way to submit, and everything else in the ajax call works.