# Textbox focus at first position of character in textbox click event-Chrome Browser Compatibility Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser

Here is my HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textname" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox" 
    OnClick="fnFocus(this.id)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Here Is JavaScript

```
function fnFocus(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).focus();
}
```

The above code is working in all browsers except Chrome. On `textbox` click event I want to show focus at the first character of the input.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do you get any errors on chrome? or if you put an alert do you get the correct id?

Comment: No errors.. but not giving expected output

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096436/document-getelementbyidid-focus-is-not-working-for-firefox-or-chrome