# What is setTimeout doing when set to 0 milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

In JavaScript, `setTimeout(callback, delay)` means "call `callback` after `delay` milliseconds". But what if `delay` is `0`? Should it call `callback` right away?

I am confused because of what I see when I run the following code:

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log('AAA');
}, 0); // Call this in 0 milliseconds 

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log('BBB'); 
}
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log('CCC'); 
}
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log('DDD'); 
}
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log('EEE'); 
}
```

This logs the following to the console:

[image: console_log]

I expected to see `AAA` logged much sooner than that. There was time to execute 4000 other calls to `console.log` before a function which should have been called immediately.

Can someone explain what `setTimeout` is doing when the delay is set to 0 milliseconds?

Comment: Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: A great explanation on your question! Check [this](http://geekabyte.blogspot.in/2014/01/javascript-effect-of-setting-settimeout.html).

Comment: Thanks for the links, great explanations. I would still keep my question open (as not duplicate) as it is showing the direct effect in a very simple way.

Comment: Looks like you dont know what is the `callbacks`

Answer (score 118, accepted):

A few useful facts might help clarify what's happening:

1. JavaScript is single-threaded. Asynchronous callbacks are assigned to a *message* placed in a *message queue*.
2. When no code is currently executing, the *event loop* polls the message queue, requesting the next message in line to be processed (executed).
3. `setTimeout` adds a message (with the callback provided) to the end of this queue after the specified delay has elapsed.

(Note: this means the delay in a `setTimeout` call is not a sure thing; it is the **minimum delay** before the callback is executed. The actual time taken depends on how long it takes to process any messages ahead of it in the queue.)

So what happens if the delay is set to `0`? A new message is added to the queue immediately, and will be processed when the currently executing code is finished and any previously-added messages have been processed.

## What's happening in your code

When you invoke `setTimeout`…

```
setTimeout(function() { 
    console.log('AAA');
}, 0);
```

…a message gets added to the queue with the specified callback. The rest of your code…

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    console.log('BBB'); 
}
// etc.
```

…continues executing synchronously. Once it has completely finished, the event loop polls the message queue for the next message and finds the one with your `setTimeout` callback, which is then processed (the callback is run).

The callback only ever gets executed *after* the currently executing code has finished, no matter how long that takes.

## Further reading

For more details on the event loop, see:

- [*Concurrency model and event loop*—MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)
- [*The JavaScript event loop: explained*—Carbon Five](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/)

Comment: *"(Note: this means the delay in a setTimeout call is not a sure thing…)"* I never considered this.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Nice and concise answer that gives a good initial idea. Until now the best I found to this subject in terms of information/brevity quota. Thanks!