# How to preserve focus in Angular 5 with changing input number field?

Tags: angular, angular5, focus

I have an ordered table with a field on one entity which you can change to "re-rank" that row on the table:

```
 <table>
  <thead>
    <th>Rank</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let entity of entities">
      <td>
        <input *ngIf='entity === currentEntity' 
                value="{{entity.Rank}}" 
                type="number" 
                min="1"
                max="{{entities.length}}"
                (change)="updateRank(entity, $event)">
        <span *ngIf='entity !== currentEntity'>{{entity.Rank}}</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>{{entity.Name}}</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So the number input is only for the current entity, and on a change, I re-rank these in the back-end and update the ordering on the UI.

This works great, but the issue is that when you are using the **arrow keys** to change the rank, the focus is only preserved when decreasing the rank. When you increase the rank, the focus is removed from the input box.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JustinDao/t0hwLu4b/ (try on Chrome or Firefox)

I think this is due to how Angular creates the DOM elements, but I'm not entirely sure. Is there a way for me to preserve the focus when increasing the rank as well?

Comment: I don't understand the requirement (what exactly you're achieving). Temporary solution : https://jsfiddle.net/shantanu_k/tswk8acn/

Comment: I want the user to be able to use the arrow keys to re-rank the rows on the table easily. 

I see that your fiddle does just that! Why do you need the setTimeout() here?

Comment: There's a bug in your code - it uses Angular instead of React.
(jk jk jk)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JustinDao/mcu1tb90/ Here is a fiddle with @Shantanu 's fix, with a slightly more elegant way to grab the object (passing it into the method itself) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955650 seems to be the explanation of why this works - the DOM element doesn't exist yet, so you queue a message with `.focus()` so that the DOM updates, then the `.focus()` call is made. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/JustinDao/mcu1tb90

The fix is to do a `setTimeout` to set the focus on the `input`.

Passing the `input` object into the method:

```
<input #myInput
       *ngIf='entity === currentEntity' 
       value="{{entity.Rank}}" 
       type="number" 
       min="1"
       max="{{entities.length}}"
       (change)="updateRank(entity, $event, myInput)">
```

Then in `updateRank`

```
updateRank(entity, event, inputObject) {
    ....
    setTimeout(() => {
        inputObject.focus();
    });
}
```

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33955650 has an explanation of why this works. Basically, the DOM element doesn't exist yet, so you queue a message with `.focus()` by using `setTimeout` so that the DOM updates, then the `.focus()` call is made.