# Add synchronous processing CSS and asynchronous processing alert

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling

I have a question regarding asynchronous processing.

```
User
if(myTurn) {
    item.setAttribute('class', 'black');
} else {
    item.setAttribute('class', 'white');
}

// 승리 체크
if (checkWin(row, col, turn)) {
    let winner = myTurn ? '흑돌' : '백돌';
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(winner + ' 승!');
        location.reload();
    }, 0);
}
```

Looking at the logic above, the logic for adding classes is processed synchronously, and the logic for displaying alerts is processed asynchronously.

an alert appears before CSS changes due to class addition. If you set milliseconds to 10, the alert will appear late as expected.

Is this because asynchronous alerts run faster than CSS changes?

I understand that the event loop exits and asynchronous processing is executed, but I don't understand why the alert appears before the CSS changes.

Comment: I'm hesitant to close as a duplicate (it'd be a 1-vote close for me, so it's worth being cautious sometimes), but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33955650/328193) is *probably* the information you're looking for.  There may be differences that I'm not aware of (hence the hesitation) in how re-styling and re-rendering is done in the browser with regards to the event loop.  But in the JavaScript code itself that timeout is simply going to be the next thing to execute as soon as control reaches the end of the synchronous code (in this case as soon as it exits that `if` block).

Comment: Setting the `class` attribute like that is not a good idea. You may eventually have classes that have unrelated semantics. Instead, use the `.classList` API, and so to add a class use `item.classList.add("black")` and `item.classList.remove("white")` etc.