# SweetAlert, Focusing an input after Confirm

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, confirm, sweetalert

Basically I have a form where you can add an User.

```
<div class="container">
    <div><h1>Formulario para agregar Usuarios</h1></div>
  <form id='addForm' role="form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-lg-6">

        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="15" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre"/>
            <div id="nom" name="nom"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="apellido">Apellido:</label>            
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido" maxlength="15" placeholder="Ingrese su Apellido" />
            <div id="ape" name="ape"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="correo">Correo:</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" id="correo" name="correo" maxlength="30" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.cl"/>
            <div id="cor" name="cor"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>            
            <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Ingrese una Contraseña (mínimo 6 caracteres)" />
            <div id="pas" name="pas"></div>
        </div>      
        <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default col-sm-2" id="addUser" name="addUser" type="submit" >
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Agregar</button>
        </div>

           <div class="form-group col-sm-8" id="userData" name="userData"></div>         

    </div>
```

After success a sweet alert appears on screen telling you the add worked.

Before the `swal` I had a normal alert, and after showing success It would focus on the first input of the form.

But now when the `swal` shows up, It gives the focus while swal's on screen and when you click the confirm button the focus is gone.

I tried to set `onConfirmButton` to false and then add a function

```
$.post('agregar.php', {nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido, correo: correo, password: password}, function(data) {
            //Se recibe un resultado (data) y se muestra en el div
            //(que en este caso sería una cadena string con algún mensaje)
            if (data=='1') {
                //swal("¡Hecho!", "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!", "success");
                swal({
                    title: "¡Hecho!",
                    text: "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                    function(){
                        swal.close();
                        $('#nombre').val('')
                        $('#apellido').val('');
                        $('#correo').val('');
                        $('#password').val('');
                        $('#nombre').focus();

                    })
                );
```

But it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

Use promise with "then" function like: `.then(function(){` just before closing the swal function with ";".

Using your code, it will be like that:

```
swal({
    title: "¡Hecho!",
    text: "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!",
    closeModal: false
}).then(function() {
        swal.close();
        $('#nombre').val('')
        $('#apellido').val('');
        $('#correo').val('');
        $('#password').val('');
        $('#nombre').focus();
});
```

Comment: Please update your answer, `closeOnConfirm` method is deprecated. Use `closeModal` as per newer version.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById('nombre').focus(); 
}, 0);
```

See here:

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096938)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic, but i share my solution for anyone who comes here from google search :)
as "limont" has said in github:
"A small delay 100ms was introduced before focusing the previous active element. The reason can be found here:[Github](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/900)"

and there is JsFiddle from "limonte" that help solving your problem:
[complete example](https://jsfiddle.net/y3nf3fjg/26/)

and this is my own code snippet that works:

```
        Swal({
            title: 'خطا...',
            text: 'لطفا یک شماره وارد کنید.',
            type: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'وارد کردن شماره',
            onAfterClose: () => {
                setTimeout(() => $("#Mobile").focus(), 110);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

So focus the element on close.

```
$('.TheElementSelector').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand in sweemalert
But if you open a modal so the focus on the input will get lost when you click on exit

So if you have an option to do focus (like in a callback function) do it.

Answer (score 0):

Por la linea 227 de swetalert-dev.js encuentras este código y crea esta variable $(datafocus).focus();.

```js
  // Reset the page to its previous state
  window.onkeydown = previousWindowKeyDown;
  if (window.previousActiveElement) {
    //window.previousActiveElement.focus();
    $( datafocus ).focus();
    datafocus = '';
  }
```

Y en tu html modifica así:

```html
$.post('agregar.php', {nombre: nombre, apellido: apellido, correo: correo, password: password}, function(data) {
            //Se recibe un resultado (data) y se muestra en el div
            //(que en este caso sería una cadena string con algún mensaje)
            if (data=='1') {
                //swal("¡Hecho!", "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!", "success");
                swal({
                    title: "¡Hecho!",
                    text: "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                    function(){
                        swal.close();
                        $('#nombre').val('')
                        $('#apellido').val('');
                        $('#correo').val('');
                        $('#password').val('');
                        datafocus = '#nombre';
                    })
                );
```

Comment: Can you please translate your answer to english so everyone can understand it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
Swal.fire({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: "warning",
  didClose: (e) => {
    // focus your element
  },
});
```

Hope this helps

credit to [GitHub](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1604) by [limenote](https://github.com/limonte)

Answer (score -1):

Finally I solved this just using a location.reload();

```
swal({
                    title: "¡Hecho!",
                    text: "¡Has Agregado un Usuario Nuevo!",
                    type: "success",
                    closeOnConfirm: false
                },
                function(){
                    location.reload();
                }
                );
```

And adding an autofocus attribute to the first input.

```
<input class="form-control" autofocus type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="15" placeholder="Ingrese su Nombre"/>
```