# forcing focus to remain on a form text element until the value is numeric

Tags: javascript

I have a form which has input fields that expect numbers only.

I'm using javascript to validate the form when the value of the field changes.
If the value is numeric, do nothing.

If the value is not numeric, set it to zero and put focus in that text field. Essentially, I'm trying to trap the cursor in that field until a numeric value is entered. For some unknown reason, focus is not being placed on that form element. `cell.focus()` does not work. I've even tried `document.getElementById(cel.getAttribute("ID")).focus();` What might I be doing wrong?

```
<html>        
<head>
    <script>
        function NAN(cell){
          if (cell.value != "") {
              var re = /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
               if (re.test(cell.value) == false) {
                 alert('You must supply a numeric value greater than 0.');
                 cell.value = "0";
             cell.focus();

           }
          }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="num" value="" onchange="NAN(cell)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code example has an error, try to put this as paramter of NAN.
then if I understood well you, it works

Comment: Bad obtrusive UX.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things done:

- You have to change *cell* to *this* with onchange.
- According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096436/2401386) at least with Firefox *setTimeout* has to wrap this focus-method so that it works as expected.

And a more user-friendly approach is inserted as well at the second input-field.

Hope this example helps you:

```js
function NAN(cell) {
  if (cell.value != '') {
    var re = /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
    cell.value = cell.value[0]=='0'?+cell.value:cell.value;
    if (re.test(cell.value) == false) {
      alert('You must supply a numeric value greater than 0.');
      cell.value = '0';
      setTimeout(function () { 
        cell.select();
        cell.focus();
      }, 0); 
    }
  }
}

/*
* a more user friendly approach
*/
function NAN2(cell) {
  if (cell.value != '') {
    var re = /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/;
    cell.value = cell.value[0]=='0'?+cell.value:cell.value;
    if (re.test(cell.value) == false) {
      alert('You must supply a numeric value greater than 0.');
      cell.value = '0';
      setTimeout(function () { 
        cell.select();
        cell.focus();
        markElement(cell);
      }, 0); 
    }
    else{
        tickElement(cell);  
    }
  }
}

function tickElement(cell){
  cell.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid green');   
}

function markElement(cell){
  cell.setAttribute('style','border: 1px solid red');   
}
```

```html
<p>
  Your approach(onchange): 
  <input type="text" name="num" value="" onchange="NAN(this)"/>
</p>

<p>
  Or you can use a more user friendly approach to notify an user right now when they are tipping something wrong (onkeyup):
  <input type="text" name="num" value="" onkeyup="NAN2(this)"/>
  
</p>
```

Comment: Now focus works as well. Please have a look on this answer. And tell me whether it is what you want.

Comment: Supplying an integer value like 01, 02 etc fails. Please verify.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh: You are right. I've adapted my code accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I did not understand why cell.focus() was not placing focus. I've used it many times before.  I did not know that I needed to add cell.select() before calling focus(). Why I need to select the cell first, I do not know, but it works and I am happy.

As far as this being a client side script, I will test the value on the server and if it is not a number, not try to insert it into an integer field in my database. That's what caused the error in the first place. Someone tried to enter '1 or 2' instead of a number.

Comment: Its kind of practise to use cell.select() cell.focus() in combination, you could also use cell.focsu() alone. If you accept this answer to be right, then please tick it to make it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the `onchange` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="num" value="" onchange="NAN(cell)"/>
```

The value is executed as JavaScript code directly. You're passing code, not just a generic signature or prototype.

Inside those event handler snippets, there's a special object `this` defined, referring to the current DOM element (the `input` tag in this example).

(Just to mention it, there is also a second predefined object `event`, which most likely caused your confusion.)

As a simple fix for your issue, replace `cell` with `this` in the call and it should work:

```
<input type="text" name="num" value="" onchange="NAN(this)"/>
```

---

It's also important to note that you should keep in mind that this verification requires JavaScript to be executed. If it's disabled, the user might still pass any values, so you should check the value server side as well (assuming this isn't just client-only code).

As an alternative to using JavaScript, you could just use HTML5 to force a specific pattern on inputs. In this case this would be trivial to do:

```
<input type="text" name="num" value="" pattern="(?!0)\d+" title="Quantity">
```

The user won't be able to submit the form unless the pattern is validated, so there's no need to force the input focus. The pattern always has to match the full value, from beginning to the end. The `title` attribute is typically used to provide more information in the error popup.

Comment: I would even mark your answer as right, but form-patterns are supported by IE 11 that is still too high. I can not wait until this day comes :)